# Equivalent path on RESELLER account?

Tags: php, path, shared-hosting

I use this $path in my Hostgator **Shared Hosting** accounts and it works perfectly:

```
$path = dirname($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]).'/';
```

I.e. this path is **/home/username/public_html/**

Here's an example of how I use it:

```
<?php 
$path = dirname($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]).'/';
include($path.'stats.php');
?>
```

My problem is that this $path *doesn't* work in my new Hostgator **Reseller** account.

Does anyone know why this doesn't work for Reseller hosting and what $path I can use instead?

Ideally I'd then use an "if else" so that I could use the same code on my Shared and Reseller accounts.

Would the following work:

```
<?php 
if(strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'],$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])===false) {
        // for reseller accounts
        $path = WHATEVER_THE_RESELLER_PATH_IS;
    }
    else {
        // for shared hosting accounts
        $path = dirname($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]).'/';
    }
include($path.'stats.php');
?>
```

I got the above "if" from here: [PHP strange DOCUMENT_ROOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001326/php-strange-document-root).

Answer (score 0):

`dirname(__FILE__);` will point to the directory of the file executing this statement. if you know where it is you can find your document root this way.

Answer (score 0):

I would not build apps to be dependent on `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` always having a consistent relationship to your web root. Your application(s) should be loosely coupled to their hosting environment: They should know as little about it as possible, so that there are fewer issues moving between environments.

For example, WordPress uses the `ABSPATH` constant to store the absolute path to the WordPress directory:

The file: `/example/hosting/env/public_html/blog/wp-config.php`

would have the line of code:

```
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```

WordPress knows where all of it's files are relative to the directory that holds `wp-config.php`, and so builds all of it's file paths relative to that. The next line of code down from that is:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

After `ABSPATH` is defined, it is used as the base file-path for the rest of WordPress.

Comment: Hi Shad, thanks for this. Forgive me, I'm a beginner at this kind of thing.

Comment: So, you're saying I should set my path to be `$path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/';` ?  This doesn't work for Shared Hosting. Hence why I chose to use `$path = dirname($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]).'/';` which works fine on Shared hosting. Are you saying that I should use `$path = define('APP_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');` and that will work, not just for shared hosting but for any hosting?  Sorry, I'm confused.  I use my code in hooks in my Headway framework theme (wordpress).

Comment: @PhilDean Answer updated, let me know if that answers your questions